# Object is possible undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined, angular11

I don't understand why I'm getting the 'Object is possibly undefined error' on this.selectedBugReport. I make sure that it can't be undefined and store the result in a constant. But that, is a problem for Angular?

**Error**

```
const test = this.selectedBugReport !== undefined;
if (test) // if (test === true) also errors
{
  // @ts-ignore
  const i = this.selectedBugReport.id; // << no error because of ignore

  const h = this.selectedBugReport.id; // <<< error!!
}
```

**No error**

```
if (this.selectedBugReport !== undefined)
{
  // @ts-ignore
  const i = this.selectedBugReport.id; // << no error

  const h = this.selectedBugReport.id; // <<< no error
}
```

I'm using Angular 11 and the WebStorm IDE if it matters.

**Update:**

Is this the best practice hack to make it work (for more complex cases to avoid 100+ if-statements)?

```
const test: MyDto = this.selectedBugReport as MyDto; // This line looks stupid to me.
const foo = test.id; // no error, no if-checks required anymore.
```

Comment: Shouldn't top `if` be `if(this.selectedBugReport)`?

Comment: This is a typescript issue, not angular specific. You’ll have to correcty type this.selectedBugReport. What you did with the !== undefined will just make it a boolean by inference so that won’t work..

Comment: So if I have such a case inside a more 'complex' case, like a nested ternary operator, then I have to perform the if-check like 5x on EVERY single line where it applies? I can't define a constant for it? That seems both inefficient and hard to maintain...

Example for a FormGroup:
selectProject: [this.isEdit ? this.selectedBugReport === undefined ? projectId : -1 : <insert more ternary nonsense here>]
That's a single line and it will contain like 5 if-checks each... Gonna be a lot of if-checks... And I know 100% sure that it can't be undefined.

Comment: You can just do `const test = this.selectedBugReport as MyDto;` or `const test: MyDto = this.selectedBugReport;` (depending on how `selectedBugReport` is typed). Only one side needs to be explicitly typed. And it's not a hack; it's being clear on what type your objects are. You don't need any `if`s, if you've typed your objects and properties correctly.

Comment: I thought this was a hack but apparently, this is the go-to solution then. If you can post this as an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: I would if(this.selectedBugReport) or use nullsafe `this.selectedBugReport?.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type assertion like `MyDto` is good but I recommend add this to tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        // .... 
    }
}
```

This is safe for runtime errors.